# handle multipart/formdata, application/json, and text/plain in single express handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express demo server that echoes back what the client POSTs to it.

It's used in a learning activity where the client will POST with the fetch API, e.g.:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:5000/', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({ lab: 'fetch', status: 'fun' }),
  headers: messageHeaders
})
```

The `body` of the data will be a string, JSON, or [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

I'm not super familiar with express, but I'd like to just have a single route that handles all three `body` types. Currently I'm not able to figure out how to do that.

I started with [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244174/serving-multiple-content-types), but the solution not working for my case - I don't think the [res.format](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.format) API allows me to access the body of the request, nor does it seem to work with multi-part form data.

Instead I've defaulted to using the [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) and [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) packages in a potential middle-ware-hack configuration:

```js
// if client POST body is a string, parse as text
app.post('/', bodyParser.text(), (req, res, next) => {
  const contentType = req.get('content-type');
  if (!contentType.includes('text/plain')) {
    return next();
  }
  res.write(JSON.stringify(req.headers, null, 2))
  res.write('\n\n')
  res.write(req.body)
  res.end()
});

// if client POST body is JSON, parse as JSON
app.post('/', bodyParser.json(), (req, res, next) => {
  const contentType = req.get('content-type');
  if (!contentType.includes('application/json')) {
    return next();
  }
  res.write(JSON.stringify(req.headers, null, 2))
  res.write('\n\n')
  res.write(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
  res.end()
});

// if client POST body is FormData, parse as form-data
app.post('/', upload.fields([]), (req, res, next) => {
  const contentType = req.get('content-type');
  if (!contentType.includes('multipart/form-data')) {
    return next();
  }
  res.write(JSON.stringify(req.headers, null, 2))
  res.write('\n\n')
  res.write(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
  res.end()
});
```

is there a more standard or "better" pattern to achieve this functionality? Perhaps where I only need to write a single handler?

Comment: I think what you have done there is fine, what problem is it giving you?

Comment: No bug. Just not familiar with express & seems like a single handler would be a better or more canonical pattern. I would think a server framework could parse different types of input in a single route but I didn't find any sample code for this situation. If it's legit then I'm happy to accept that.

Comment: You could do in a single route, by creating instances of your `bodyParser` etc, and then attach onto it's next event.  eg.  `var bodyparser_text = bodyParser.text();` and then inside the route,.. `if (somecondition) bodyparser_text(req, res, function (req, res) { /*rest of code*/})`, or something like that.. not tested..

Comment: hmm. I tried what you suggested (at least my flawed interpretation of what you suggested) unsuccessfully. I don’t think the `bodyParser` / etc API really supports that? looks like `bodyParser` only takes an `options` config object, and isn’t used directly with callbacks inside of it and such. I think I figured out what I was going for tho - see my suggested answer

Comment: First you should do `app.use(bodyParser.json());` then on your route `app.post('/notes', multer.array("files", 5), (req, res)=> {});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner solution might be for you to pass the middle-wares as array to the specific route, it will eventually get parsed.

```
app.post('/notes', [urlencodedParser, multiPart.array("files", 5)], (req, res)=> {
   //do what you want
   console.log(req.files);// to get the files
   console.log(req.body);// to get the body 
})
```

You can however use the `app.use(middleware:parser);` but note that with this, the middle ware function will be called for all routes handled by express within your application.

so i think handling it on specific route that need this sort of dynamism is neater and probably of better performance.

Comment: yeah that makes even more sense, especially in the case that I have other routes that don't need to access all three parsers. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think I just misunderstood express concepts (this could potentially be a poor question).

I assumed I had to use these body parsing functions (`multer` / `upload.fields`, `bodyParser`) as callbacks in my route, e.g.:

```
router.post('/', /* parsing callback */, function(req, res) {
  // ..
});
```

or that I could use the parsers inside a route, e.g.:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  if (condition) {
     /* parserA */
  } else {
     /* parserB */
  }
});
```

With the former, I wasn't sure how to use multiple parser for different content types in a single route, and with the latter, I couldn't actually find the API signature for using the parsers directly (which is still a little weird to me, maybe I didn't search well enough?).

But in any case, I was able to condense my code into a single & much cleaner route by using all the parsers outside the route(s). The final code looks more like:

```
const upload = multer();
app.use(upload.fields([]));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.text());

app.post('/', (req, res) => {

  res.write(JSON.stringify(req.headers, null, 2))
  res.write('\n\n')

  const contentType = req.get('content-type');

  if (contentType.includes('text/plain')) {
    res.write(req.body)
  }

  if (contentType.includes('application/json') ||
      contentType.includes('multipart/form-data')) {
    res.write(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
  }

  res.end()

});
```

Here I'm basically calling all three types of parsers (string, json, formdata) at the top of the app, for *every* request, and only the appropriate parser actually modifies the `req.body` property. So then in the route itself, I can just send data back based on the content type with the appropriate parsing already done.

**Edit**: @Keith pointed out that this implementation is likely less performant, since the parsers are called for each request, so it may not necessarily be a "better" solution.

Comment: In a way, that's how you would normally do things.  But with you attaching your parsers on the route, I was assuming you was doing it for performance reasons.  With express if you know a route does not need a middleware you can leave it out, and then include it in the other routes that do.  Here every request is now going to do a check, and then pass on to the next middleware until one handles it.  Not really sure why the suggestion of calling the middleware directly didn't work though.  All middlewares are just a function callback in the form `(req, res, next)`

Comment: ah i see, that is a good point. Idk how the parsers are implemented, but i would hope they're wrapped in a simple conditional check & call `next()` if they shouldn't parse the request, so that only the correct parser actually does significant computation. Thanks for all your input! If its worth your effort to submit a second answer with more explicit code I'd be glad to test & accept your suggested implementation. But I can't get it working myself. No worries either way.